# Jquery DataTable after calling the JasonResult method and showing data with scrolling function, Column footer does not align with its data column

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables

I am trying to find the total of 'Net Value' and ' Total Value' in datatable as footer and the total value should be shown inside td element with the same alignment of its other data column. If I try to add footer , the total column shows different position from its data column. The footer should be showed the same column of its data.    Here is my code in html. Since I am not able to show the original program , I had to make it in presentable format. I am showing the data by calling JsonResult method from the controller , But after fetching the data from the Jsonmethod and showing the result in datatable with vertical scrolling, the footer value is showed bit far from its data column

```
 @model myModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%;font-size:90%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Item
                                </th>

                                <th>
                                    Net Value
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Total Value
                                </th>
                                
                            </tr>

                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="body">

                            <tr>
                                <td>Item</td>
                                <td>NetVal</td>
                                <td>TotVal</td>                              
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>                                
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var report = {};
            report.FromDate = "@Model.FromDate";
            report.ToDate = "@Model.ToDate";
            report.CustomerCode = "@Model.CustomerCode";
            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/mySales/SalesData",
                    "data": report,
                    "dataSrc": function (json) {
                        console.log(json);
                        return JSON.parse(json);
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Item" },
                    { "data": "NetVal" },
                    { "data": "TotVal" },                  
                ],
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"
                    },
                    { "width": "10%", "targets": 0 },
                    { "width": "5%", "targets": 1 },
                    { "width": "5%", "targets": 2 },                   
                ],
                "pageLength": 40,
                scrollY: "500px",
                scrollX: true,
                paging: true,
                footerCallback: function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                    var api = this.api(), data;
                    var intVal = function (i) {
                        return typeof i === 'string' ?
                            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                            typeof i === 'number' ?
                                i : 0;
                    };

                    var col1 = api
                        .column(1)
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    var col2 = api
                        .column(2)
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    $(api.column(1).footer()).html(col1);
                    $(api.column(2).footer()).html(col1);
                    
                },
                scrollCollapse: true,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copyHtml5',
                    'excelHtml5',
                    'csvHtml5',
                    'pdfHtml5'

                ]

            })
        })
    </script>


// Controller
public JsonResult SalesData(myModel model)
        {
            DateTime fromDate = new DateTime();
            DateTime toDate = new DateTime();
            if (report.FromDate != "" && report.ToDate != "" && report.FromDate != null && report.ToDate != null)
            {
                fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(report.FromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(report.ToDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            report.CustomerCode = "001";
            var data = _unitOfWork.GetSummary(report.CustomerCode, fromDate, toDate);
            String jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            return Json(jsonResult);
    

}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you are describing. Everything looks normal when I run your code. Can you provide a screenshot to clarify "_the footer is showed bit far from its data column_"? As well as this, you also need to provide a [mre] so we can recreate what you are seeing. Also, what is `$('#container')`? That is not defined in your code.

Comment: Minor point: Why is this question tagged as `asp.net-core`? That appears to be irrelevant - and, if so, it should be removed.

Comment: Also: Make sure the number of `<td>` elements in each HTML row matches the number of `<th>` in the header and footer of the table. Your HTML needs to be a well-formed table.

Comment: I tested it with your code according to SelVazi's method, but there is no alignment error. Is your mistake a header (th) misalignment problem? Try to add a fixed table layout to the table: `<table style="table-layout:fixed"></table>`.

Comment: Many Thanks , it was the problem with table layout, I changed my layout as you advised and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter `scrollCollapse: true`

This parameter (when enabled) will cause DataTables to collapse the table's viewport when the result set fits within the given Y height.

[docs here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollCollapse)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
     "pageLength": 40,
      scrollY: '500px',
      scrollCollapse: true,
      scrollX: true,
      paging: true,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
                { extend: 'copyHtml5', footer: true },
                { extend: 'excelHtml5', footer: true },
                { extend: 'csvHtml5', footer: true },
                { extend: 'pdfHtml5', footer: true }
      ]
 });
$('#container').css('display', 'block');
table.columns.adjust().draw();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%;font-size:90%">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
       Item
    </th>
    <th>
       Net Value
    </th>
    <th>
       Total Value
    </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>200.00</td>
      <td>300.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>300.00</td>
      <td>200.00</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
    <tr>
       <th>Total</th>
       <td>First Total</td>
       <td>Second Total</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added  'scrollCollapse: true', but still not working

Comment: If you are testing using your table, you have an error there .. you have a row with 6 columns it should be 3 only

Comment: Actually in my original program it was only 3 column, that was my typing error.

Comment: Hi SelVazi, I have given more details in my program. The alignment is going wrong after If I calling the JsonResult method and bringing the data into datatable with vertical scrollbar.